# Recordscount showing 1 even even WHERE criteria is an empty set

Tags: vba, vb6, ado

The following SQL statement and code return aaa=1 when it should obviously be null

```
> Private Sub Command1_Click()
>     strSql = "SELECT MAX(fromdate) from TipulimPricing   WHERE 1=2"
>     '****************************
>     CreateTheConnectionTargetTemplate
>     '**************************** '    objRecordset.MoveFirst
>     aaa = objRecordset.RecordCount
>     MyVal = objRecordset.Fields(0).Value
>     ' ****************************
>     ReleaseTheConnection
>     '**************************** End Sub
```

Comment: `when it should obviously be null` - and it is. And to deliver that null to you, there has to be one row in the recordset.

Comment: To add on to what @GSerg said, this is because of the `MAX()` function. `MAX()` is required to return a value. If you had done instead `SELECT fromdate FROM table WHERE 1=2` you would get zero records, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are either using a DAO type recordset, or ADO with single record keyset.

What you can do to calculate the number of records is to create a loop with a counter:

```
Do while objRecordset.EOF = False
    counter = counter +1
    objRecordset.moveNext
Loop
```

Comment: you did miss the point: The SQL statement will return ONE row (no matter how many records are in the DB matching the where clause due to the aggregating function max() - would be the same for min(), sum(), count(), etc ....)

Comment: Well, the count() would produce an actual zero.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor oh, you're right. I have misread the tittle. Although as itsLex said, it would still work, since if there were no matching criteria, then the resulted record would be EOF.